# Serde class for AVRO primitive type

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I'm writing a Kafka stream app in Java that takes input topics created by a connector that uses the schema registry and avro for both the key and value converter. The connector produces the following schemas:

```
key-schema: "int"
value-schema:{
"type": "record",
"name": "User",
"fields": [
    {"name": "firstname", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "lastname",  "type": "string"}
]}
```

Actually, there are several topics, the key-schema is always "int" and the value-schema is always a record of some kind (User, Product, etc). My code contains the following definitions

```
Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl);

Serde<User> userSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
userSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
```

At first I tried consuming the topic with something like 
`Consumed.with(Serdes.Integer(), userSerde);` but that did not work because Serdes.Integer() expects integers to be encoded using 4 bytes but avro uses a variable length encoding. Using `Consumed.with(Serdes.Bytes(), userSerde);` worked but I really wanted int and not bytes so I changed my code to this

```
KafkaAvroDeserializer keyDeserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer()
KafkaAvroSerializer keySerializer = new KafkaAvroSerializer();
keyDeserializer.configure(serdeConfig, true); 
keySerializer.configure(serdeConfig, true);
Serde<Integer> keySerde = (Serde<Integer>)(Serde)Serdes.serdeFrom(keySerializer, keyDeserializer);
```

This made the compiler produce a warning (it doesn't like the `(Serde<Integer>)(Serde)` casting) but it allows me to use

`Consumed.with(keySerde, userSerde);` and get an integer as the key. This works just fine and my app is behaving as expected (great!!!). But now I want to define default serde for the key/value and I cannot get it to work.

Setting the default value serde is simple:

```
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
```

However I cannot figure out how to define the default key serde.

I tried

1. `streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, keySerde.getClass().getName());`
   Produces runtime error: Could not find a public no-argument constructor for org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$WrapperSerde
2. `streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);`
   Produces runtime error: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like your casting. Ignoring the error makes attempt 2 (SpecificAvroSerde.class) not work, because the types do not match. So it seems from what you say, the key is actually avro data. The fact your avro only contains definition for user id (now) doesn't mean it is integer type, because you can add new fields later. It's fine though to construct custom serde to read Avro data and only return user id as Integer (then this is correctly Serde<Integer>). If you do this, you also need custom serde for writing that takes Integer userId value and writes Avro key data (is containing user id).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update** *(version 5.5 and newer)*

Confluent version `5.5` adds native support for primitive Avro types via `PrimitiveAvroSerde` (cf. https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/5.5.x/avro-serde/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/streams/serdes/avro/PrimitiveAvroSerde.java)

**Original answer** *(version 5.4 and older)*:

It's a known issues. Primitive Avro types don't work well with Confluent's AvroSerdes, because the Serdes works with `GenericAvroRecord` and `SpecificAvroRecord` only.

Compare https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/tree/master/avro-serde/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/streams/serdes/avro.

Thus, building you own Serde based on `KafkaAvroSerializer` and `KafkaAvroDeserializer` is the right approach. To be able to pass this into the config as default Serde, you cannot use `Serdes.serdeFrom` because the type information is lost due to genrics type erasure.

However, you can implement you own class that extends `Serde` interface instead and pass your custom class into the config:

```java
public class MySerde extends Serde<Integer> {
    // use KafkaAvroSerializer and KafkaAvroDeserializer and cast `Object` to `Integer`
}

config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, MySerde.class);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I ended up doing. It just felt wrong that I had to do so much to get serialization/deserialization of a primitive avro type working.

Comment: We need to close this gap... Confluent Schema Registry is an open source project. Feel free to contribute this improvement: https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the hint from @Matthias J. Sax , I would like to post the work around solution.please free to enhance it.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer;

public class GenericPrimitiveAvroSerDe<T> implements Serde<T> {

    private final Serde<Object> inner;

    /**
     * Constructor used by Kafka Streams.
     */
    public GenericPrimitiveAvroSerDe() {
        inner = Serdes.serdeFrom(new KafkaAvroSerializer(), new KafkaAvroDeserializer());
    }

    public GenericPrimitiveAvroSerDe(SchemaRegistryClient client) {
        this(client, Collections.emptyMap());
    }

    public GenericPrimitiveAvroSerDe(SchemaRegistryClient client, Map<String, ?> props) {
        inner = Serdes.serdeFrom(new KafkaAvroSerializer(client), new KafkaAvroDeserializer(client, props));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final Map<String, ?> serdeConfig, final boolean isSerdeForRecordKeys) {
        inner.serializer().configure(serdeConfig, isSerdeForRecordKeys);
        inner.deserializer().configure(serdeConfig, isSerdeForRecordKeys);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        inner.serializer().close();
        inner.deserializer().close();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Serializer<T> serializer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object obj = inner.serializer();
        return (Serializer<T>) obj;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Deserializer<T> deserializer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object obj = inner.deserializer();
        return (Deserializer<T>) obj;

    }

}
```

Usage as default stream config:

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,GenericPrimitiveAvroSerDe.class);
            props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,GenericPrimitiveAvroSerDe.class);
```

Overriding the defaults:

```
final Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url",
                                                                        "http://localhost:8081");
       final GenericPrimitiveAvroSerDe<String> keyGenericAvroSerde = new GenericPrimitiveAvroSerDe<String>();
       keyGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, true); // `true` for record keys
       final GenericPrimitiveAvroSerDe<Long> valueGenericAvroSerde = new GenericPrimitiveAvroSerDe<Long>();
       valueGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false); // `false` for record values
```

Comment: This functioniality would be pretty useful in the standard project

Answer (score 1):

Also if you want use the great solution of @Thiyaga Rajan with KAFKA consumers and producers

```
consumerConfig.put(KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,GenericPrimitiveAvroSerDe.class);
producerConfig.put(KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericPrimitiveAvroSerDe.class);
```

add this to the class

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;

    public class GenericPrimitiveAvroSerDe<T> implements Serde<T>, Serializer<T>, Deserializer<T> {

      @Override
      public T deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        return this.deserializer().deserialize(topic, data);
      }

      @Override
      public byte[] serialize(String topic, T data) {
        return this.serializer().serialize(topic, data);
      }

    ...

    }
```