# Deserialization PRIMITIVE AVRO KEY with kafka lib

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

I'm currently incapable of **deserialize an avro PRIMITIVE key** in a KSTREAM APP

the key in encoded with an avro schema ( registered in the schema registry ) ,

**when i use the kafka-avro-console-consumer, I can see that the key is correctly deserialize**

But impossible to make it work in a KSTREAM app

the avro schema of the key is a PRIMITIVE:

```sh
{"type":"string"}
```

I already followed the documentation of confluent

```java
final Serde<V> valueSpecificAvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
final Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
valueSpecificAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);

final Serdes.StringSerde keySpecificAvroSerde = new Serdes.StringSerde();
keySpecificAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, true);

Consumed<String, totoAvro> inputConf = Consumed.with(keySpecificAvroSerde, valueSpecificAvroSerde);

final KStream<String, totoAvro> mystream = builder.stream("name topic", inputConf);

mystream.peek((key, value) -> logger.info("topic KEY :" + key))
```

it's working well for the value, but the key is going to be a string containing the bytes from the schema registry and not only the "reel" key

https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serializer-formatter.html#wire-format

So the string key is   **/§/./11016015201**  , but I would like the reel value : **1016015201**

if I print the bytes inside the String it's [ 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x31 0x14 0x31 0x30 0x31 0x36 0x30 0x31 0x35 0x32 0x30 0x31 ]

Comment: If you key if Avro, you need to use an AvroSerde, not `StringSerde` (`StringSerde`) is for plain String type only.

Comment: Hello, thank for your help.

I'm sorry I should I said that I already tried with GenericAvroSerde

```java
Exception caught during Deserialization, taskId: 6_3, topic: myTopic, partition: 3, offset: 0 (org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndFailExceptionHandler)

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
```

It's a primitive avro schema , so it does not have a named field that I could get().

Comment: Primitive Avro types are not supported by Schema Registry. You will need to "hard code" the Avro Serde in your Streams code.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax By primitive, do you mean non-record types? They are working fine for us ... `curl schema-registry:8081/subjects/topic-key/versions/1` shows 
`{"subject":"topic-key","version":1,"id":181,"schema":"\"string\""}`

Comment: Yes, I mean non-record types. Maybe you can register them, but you cannot "use" them. Cf. https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/1177

Comment: The shipped Avro Serdes from schema registry always assume that it's a record-type. Hence, if you use a primitive type, you run into a class cast exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

it's now working : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51957801/6227500

**Original answer**

The feature is not available currently in the schema registry project.

But by implementing a custom SERDE you can manage the case ,

Thiyaga Rajan proposed a working implementation

[Serde class for AVRO primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955921/serde-class-for-avro-primitive-type/54667002#54667002)