# How to properly deserialize a kafka key that is an avro string

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams

we are using a kafka stream processor to handle some data that is being fed to us from a producer. However we are having a hard time properly handling the keys without resulting in either invisible characters or casting errors. The schema for the keys is such `'{"type": "string"}')`

The method that has been in place for a bit and mostly works, is to configure the stream as such:

```
properties.put(
    StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, 
    Serdes.String().getClass());

properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, 
    GenericAvroSerde.class);

final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
        final Serde<GenericRecord> avroSerde = new 
GenericAvroSerde();
boolean isKeySerde = false;
avroSerde.configure(
    Collections.singletonMap(                          
        AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,
        propFile.getProperty("SchemaRegistry")),
    isKeySerde);

KStream<String, GenericRecord> stream = 
    streamsBuilder.stream(inputTopic);
```

This results in key 602 looking like this `\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000R\u0006602`

Trying to use the Avro Serde on the key results in build errors:

```
properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, 
    GenericAvroSerde.class);

properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, 
    GenericAvroSerde.class);

final Serde<String> stringSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
stringSerde.configure(
    Collections.singletonMap(                            
        AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,
        propFile.getProperty("SchemaRegistry")), true);

final Serde<GenericRecord> avroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
boolean isKeySerde = false;
avroSerde.configure(
    Collections.singletonMap(                     
        AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,
        propFile.getProperty("SchemaRegistry")),
    isKeySerde);

KStream<String, GenericRecord> stream = 
    streamsBuilder.stream(inputTopic);
```

This results in build errors:
`incompatible types: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde cannot be converted to org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde<java.lang.String>`

Did anyone else hit a similar issue when building out their stream processors?

Thanks,
-Ryan

Comment: Yes, in the producer the key is `Serdes.String().getClass()` and in the consumer you use `GenericAvroSerde.class`. You should try to consume with the `Serdes.String().getClass()` !

Comment: `Serdes.String().getClass()` is what is currently in the consumer, and ends up creating strings with invisible characters at the front.

Comment: Sorry Ryan, but in your code for the consumer, at first line, you set the default Key serde to the GenericAvroSerde. Later in your code, you define a `final Serde<String> stringSerde` but you never use this. If you do not want to use the generic serdes, you explicitly have to set it when you call the stream method, like this: `stream​(java.lang.String topic, Consumed<K,V> consumed)`

Comment: Your question is the same than this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220008/deserialization-primitive-avro-key-in-kstream-app?noredirect=1#comment101254427_57220008